# how to put && operator for dynamic number of variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

```
const id = ["2m3","2n3","3nn2","46ee7".....(dynamic number of varibles)]

student.map((student)=>{
if (student.id!== id[0] && student.id !== id[1] && student.id !== id[2]...so on) {
  console.log(student);
} else {
  console.log('Not the student');
}
}
```

if (student.id!== id[0] && student.id !== id[1] && student.id !== id[2]...so on)
I want to know how to wirte this line of code to check for the correct student
I am working in a reactjs project with a mongodb backend server from where i get the student object

I want to know how to dynamicaly add && operater in the if..else statement to fullfill my needs
I don't want true or false return , I want to get the data of the exact object and work on it later on

Comment: Check if `student.id` is in the array using this syntax `if !(id.includes(student.id)):`

Comment: @Andy `every` also short-circuits

Comment: i don't want to get TRUE OR FALSE retrun, I want to work more on the exact object which matches my needs

Comment: The above comments are objectively the best (and really only way) to solve this problem. There are several different methods you can use in your `if` statement to determine if the `id` does not appear in the list, but this is the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code -

```
const id = ["2m3","2n3","3nn2","46ee7"]
student.map((student)=>{
if (!id.includes(student.id)) {
  console.log(student);
} else {
  console.log('Not the student');
}
})
```

In the above code we are using includes function of array to check whether student.id is present in that array or not.

Addition to this you can also use indexOf function of array. indexOf returns -1 if element does n't exist in array. So we can also match student.id with every element of id array using indexOf().

```
    student.map((student)=>{
        if (id.indexOf(student.id) < 0) {
        console.log(student);
     }  else {
        console.log("Not the student");
    }
})
```

I hope this will solve your query. Please let me know.

Comment: It did not work....I don't know how to explain my problem...after reading all the comments I figured out you guys helped me alot but it does not work for my logic

Comment: @ashish.oraon could you please elaborate what's the issue you are facing?